# Inner If else statement in Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

While i am executing following code,  when `if [ $c_count -eq $p_count ]` get fails then control goes directly to outer else part. But it should go to inner else part.
What is issue in this...?

```
while [ "${arr2[$j]}" != "P" ]
do
    if [ $j -ge $i ]
    then
        break
    fi

    if [ "${arr1[$j]}" == "M" -a $p_count -ne 0 ]
    then
        c_count=`grep -c "<${arr3[$j]}>" $2`

        if [ $c_count -eq $p_count ]
        then
            echo "${arr1[$j]} ${arr2[$j]} Y   $c_count    ${arr3[$j]} >>>>>"
        else
            echo "${arr1[$j]} ${arr2[$j]} N   $c_count    ${arr3[$j]} "
            mcinvalid=`expr $mcinvalid + 1`
            echo "Count Incremented"
        fi


    else
        c_count=`grep -c "<${arr3[$j]}>" $2`
        echo "${arr1[$j]} ${arr2[$j]} N   $c_count    ${arr3[$j]} -------"
    fi

    j=`expr $j + 1`
done
```

Comment: Put `set -x` in the start of the script to turn on debugging and see what actually happens and the values when you run the script.

Comment: Are you sure `[ $c_count -eq $p_count ]` is being executed?

Comment: yes it is executing. why you are asking so?